# how do i add parameters to a custom command in a custom vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

---

I decided to create my own extension which consists of 2 additional commands. One command needs to have, at least, one parameter, however; I am following a [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command), and it  doesn't explain how to add parameters. I searched for answers online, but was unable find them. Here is part of my code — it includes the command I would like to add parameters too.

---

### My Code:

```
    let testing = vscode.commands.registerCommand('github-sync.helloWorld', 
        () => {
            vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello WOrld from Github-Sync');
        });
```

---

How would I change the string in my example to be all capitals, or all lowercase? I would need a boolean parameter. How could I implement that parameter?

Comment: just give your function `() =>` an argument, `(args)=>`, then add an `args` argument to your key binding

Comment: that doesnt seem to work. i would type in the command ID and then something to fill up the arguments, and it came up with "no commands". are you sure that is how you do it? do i need to add something to package.json?

Comment: if you want parameters when you use the `Command Palette` you have to check the `args` parameter to be `undefined` and use QuickInputs and QuickSelects to get the parameters from the user. Where did you type the `command ID` and what did you use to `fill` the arguments, what said `no commands`

Comment: after looking into it some more, you cant type arguments in the command palette. so ive decided to use quickInput instead.