# I'm not entirely sure how to use QuickInput in VS-Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

i recently asked a question ["how do i add custom parameters to a custom command in a custom vs code extension"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68074330/how-do-i-add-parameters-to-a-custom-command-in-a-custom-vscode-extension) and realized through some of the comments that you cant enter parameters in the command palette. so i looked for alternate options. one i came across was quickInput which allows the user to enter text into a window. however, being new to typescript, along with having [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#QuickInput) for more knowledgeable users on my hands, i couldn't figure out how to use it. please help!

update: since "quickInput" couldn't be found, i decided to opt for "showInputBox" but wasn't sure how to use the "title" parameter. but just for testing porpuses i decided to test the following:

```
var info  = vscode.window.showInputBox();
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(info);
```

but it came up with the error:

```
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 4, '(message: string, ...items: string[]); Thenable<string | undefined>', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'Thenable<string | undefined>' is not assignable to the parameter of type 'string'.
Overload 2 of 4, '(message: string, ...items: MessageItem[]); Thenable<MessageItem | undefined>', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'Thenable<string | undefined>' is not assignable to the parameter of type 'string'. ts(2769) [29, 40]
```

i noticed it only gave overloads 1 and 2, not 3 and 4
anyway, now i need to know how to add: 1) a title to the input box, and 2) how to solve that error!!!

edit 2:
i tried this to solve the variable type problem:

```
var info = vscode.window.showInputBox();
if(typeof info === "string") {
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage(info);
}
```

and it came up with no errors but...    it took my input and didnt send it.

Comment: look at the extension examples

Comment: i didnt see any examples, but i will look again.

Comment: it also says `cannot find name 'QuickInput'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample code I have used before (modified):

```js
let inputBoxOptions = {
  ignoreFocusOut: true,
  title: "your title here"
};

// you can use the above or below ways to specify your inputBoxOptions
// 'command' is a variable I have declared elsewhere I want to use now 

inputBoxOptions.prompt = `Enter an alias for the command: ${ command } . . . . . `;
inputBoxOptions.placeHolder = `Enter an alias(es) for the ${ command } here`;

await vscode.window.showInputBox(inputBoxOptions)
  .then(arg => {
      // run your code using the inputBox 'arg' here
   });
}
```

You need to `await` the user's input.  Then use it in the `then` function or as below:

---

Or the documentation example:

```js
export async function showInputBox() {
    const result = await window.showInputBox({
        value: 'abcdef',
        valueSelection: [2, 4],
        placeHolder: 'For example: fedcba. But not: 123',
        validateInput: text => {
            window.showInformationMessage(`Validating: ${text}`);
            return text === '123' ? 'Not 123!' : null;
        }
    });
    window.showInformationMessage(`Got: ${result}`);
}
```

[basic input documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/quickinput-sample/src/basicInput.ts)

Comment: i used the lower example, and all it sent was `received ${result}`

Comment: nvm. i accidentally used '' instead of ``